# Unrelated tags should not be added to known-good (false-positive) review audits

Tags: bug, status-review, review-audits

I was through some Close-Votes review queue and was asked to review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449515/how-can-you-write-a-conditional-based-on-the-definedness-of-multiple-variables) in [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/26619071). Normally you can pick up the audit questions with a blind eye, but this one was not clear at all. My filters were set to [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) and [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)—two tags not related to the actual question itself—, so the audit added the [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) tag to this particular question (could have been [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), don't remember that clearly)

Looking at the tags of the question and seeing [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) and [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) combined I was a bit puzzled and so closed the question with "request some details and clarity" (clearly failing the audit).

> [image: screenshot]

Are the review-audits not going too far by adding tags to questions? Especially when the tags are mildly related at best?

**Update:** I changed this to a bug-report. As the comment indicated, *tag's should not be changed for good audits*

Comment: Adding irrelavant tags works on a known bad audit.  But adding them to a known good audit and expecting a user who is paying attention to not fail is ridiculous.  If someone is filtered on specific tags, you have to assume they are fluent in the technologies so would spot wrong tags and try to edit or flag